# How do I find the location (x, y, width, height) of the top left box only in this image of a table using Python openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-tesseract

I have this image and I need to find the location of **only** the top left box as well as its width and height. How can I do this using Python in openCV?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4OL2.png)

Comment: I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV/Numpy.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold to binary
- Compute the sum of black pixels in each row and each column
- Threshold the sums to counts above 80% of height and width of image
- Find all coordinates that have non-zero values in these sums
- Filter the coordinates to remove any values that are within 10 pixels of each other to avoid duplicates from lines that are thicker than 1 pixel
- Get the first and second coordinates of the the filtered coordinates as the bounds of the top left rectangle
- Crop the input image at these bounds
- Save the result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read input
img = cv2.imread("table_cells.png")
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold to binary
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# get sum of black values in rows and columns
row_sums = np.sum(thresh==0, axis=1)
column_sums = np.sum(thresh==0, axis=0)

# threshold sums to counts above 80% of hh and ww
row_sums[np.where(row_sums<0.8*ww)] = 0
column_sums[np.where(column_sums<0.8*hh)] = 0

# find coordinates that have non-zero values
row_coords = np.argwhere(row_sums>0)
column_coords = np.argwhere(column_sums>0)
num_rows = len(row_coords)
num_cols = len(column_coords)

# filter row_coords to avoid duplicates within 10 pixels
row_coords_filt = [row_coords[0]]
for i in range(num_rows-1):
    if (row_coords[i] > row_coords[i-1]+10):
        row_coords_filt.append(row_coords[i])

column_coords_filt = [column_coords[0]]
for i in range(num_cols-1):
    if (column_coords[i] > column_coords[i-1]+10):
        column_coords_filt.append(column_coords[i])

# print row_coords_filt
print('grid row coordinates:')
for c in row_coords_filt:
    print (c)

print('')

# print column_coords_filt
print('grid column coordinates:')
for c in column_coords_filt:
    print (c)

# get left, right, top, bottom of upper left rectangle
left = int(column_coords_filt[0])
right = int(column_coords_filt[1])
top = int(row_coords_filt[0])
bottom = int(row_coords_filt[1])

# crop rectangle
rectangle = img[top:bottom, left:right]

# save output
cv2.imwrite('table_cells_crop.png', rectangle)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('rectangle', rectangle)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Cropped Rectangle:

[image]

Coordinates Found:

```
grid row coordinates:
[30]
[315]
[599]
[884]

grid column coordinates:
[41]
[790]
[1540]
[2289]
```

Comment: Thank you but I get an error when I run the code:  column_coords_filt = [column_coords[0]]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: Is it the very same image?

Comment: yes, well I changed the name to the name of the image thats saved on my computer

Comment: I would have to see the image you used.

Comment: It's the same image that I uploaded to this page, it just has a different name on my program than the one you named it on your code. That's the only difference. Same image.

Comment: I do not know what to tell you. It works for me on my Mac OSX Sierra using Python 3.7 and OpenCV 3.4.8. Look at the imshow() images and see if you  can tell where it goes wrong compared the images that I posted.